# How does a php program decide what function is called first when I go to a php page?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand how a php application that is called with a POST to this URL works:

```
transliterator/romaji
```

The romaji.php looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace JpnForPhp\Transliterator;
class Romaji extends TransliterationSystem
{
    private $latinCharacters = array();
    public function __construct($system = '')
    {
        $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Romaji' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . (($system) ? $system : 'hepburn') . '.yaml';
        parent::__construct($file);
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->configuration['name']['english'] . ' (' . $this->configuration['name']['japanese'] . ')';
    }
```

TransliterationSystem looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace JpnForPhp\Transliterator;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
abstract class TransliterationSystem
{
    public $configuration = array();
    public function __construct($file)
    {
        $this->configuration = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));
    }
    public function transliterate($str)
    {
        $str = $this->preTransliterate($str);
        foreach ($this->configuration['workflow'] as $work) {
            if (!method_exists($this, $work['function'])) {
                continue;
            }
            $params = array($str);
            if (isset($work['parameters'])) {
                $params[] = $work['parameters'];
            }
            $str = call_user_func_array(array($this, $work['function']), $params);
        }
        $str = $this->postTransliterate($str);
        return $str;
    }
```

Can someone explain to me the sequence of events for when I POST to romaji.php?  Below is a link to the github if there is something that I should have included but didn't.

[For reference here's the link to github](https://github.com/mbilbille/jpnforphp/tree/master/src/JpnForPhp/Transliterator)

Comment: Is this part of a framework? If so it will depend on how that framework is constructed.

Comment: I see only some classes declaration, there will be a file in which some instances of these classes are created

Comment: @RayO'Donnell - I am not really sure.  I've never code in php and have just been asked to try and implement some of the functionality that is there in this github.

Comment: In the github the only place I see the classes created is in the test library.  Would they be created automatically when the page is referenced? Sorry I really don't know anything much at all about php.

Comment: No, they're not created automatically - there needs to be code written elsewhere to create them. PHP has similar syntax to C++ and Java, in terms of how classes are instantiated - if you have any experience with those languages then it'll be quite familiar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally a PHP file is read (and evaluated) from top to bottom. As pointed out in a comment above, these are just class declarations - there's no code there to actually instantiate the classes or do anything with them, so there's really nothing happening here as such.

For something to happen, there would need to be some code to make use of these classes, for example:

```
$r = new Romaji();
// Do something with $r ....
```

**EDIT:**

I just had a look at the GitHub link, and apparently this is a library; so you'll call it from your own code - it won't do anything by itself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a look at the GitHub and for your answer.

Comment: Following up on your suggestion I had a hard look at the demos but don't see any place where there is anything like = new Romaji().   I also note that using fiddler I can issue just the request: http://jpnforphpdemos.nebuleux.be/transliterator/romaji with payload and it returns the page I need. So I am confused and still cannot see where the classes are being called.

Comment: Did a search on the github and the only places where new Romaji appears are in TransliteratorTest.php   So now very confused as to how these classes are called.

Comment: You're right, I just looked again and the demo site only shows the library working, not how to use it. I'll remove the link from my answer. :-)

Comment: I think you're looking for complexity where none exists.... you just have to write a script which accepts POST input from the user, then instantiates the classes from the library which you need (using the `new` operator) and calls their methods are required, then finally returns a response to the user. So, for example, if your new script is called `translate.php` and is in the root of your website, then you'd POST to http://your.website.com/translate.php. How you write the script is beyond the scope of this question & answer; you'll need to read up on basic PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who wrote this library :)
JpnForPhp exposes various helper and functions, that's why you don't see any instanciation like `= new Romaji()` ; the transliterator component doesn't call himself :)

If you want to see some sample to understand how to use it, please check the [test files](https://github.com/mbilbille/jpnforphp/tree/master/tests/JpnForPhp) or the demo website [source code](https://github.com/Akeru/jpnforphp/blob/demo/web/index.php)

Hope this help.